# CSS Grid - Difference Between flex-start and Start Value in alignment/justifying Properties

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm a newbie in CSS Grid, after searching in Google, I haven't found what I seek for, I wonder in alignment and justifying properties, what is the difference between flex-start/flex-end and start/end value please?

Comment: Are you asking about CSS Grid or Flexbox?

Comment: Grid firstly but if there is also a difference in flexbox I'm interested to know what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no difference

**flex-start**

For items that are not children of a flex container, this value is treated like `start`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#values

Answer (score 4):

On my experience:

- flex-start and flex-end target Flexboxs items specifically.
- start and end target other items.

Here [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#Syntax):

```
/* Positional alignment */

justify-content: center;     /* Pack items around the center */

justify-content: start;      /* Pack items from the start */

justify-content: end;        /* Pack items from the end */

justify-content: flex-start; /* Pack flex items from the start */

justify-content: flex-end;   /* Pack flex items from the end */

justify-content: left;       /* Pack items from the left */

justify-content: right;      /* Pack items from the right */
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try out this [game.](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)
It will give you enough practice for Flexbox. 
Now, there are 2 properties which use flex-start/flex-end.

- ***justify-content***:The justify-content property aligns the flexible container's items when the items do not use all available space on the main-axis (horizontally).
  It means justify-content helps to align content horizontally.
- ***align-items***: The align-items property specifies the default alignment for items inside the flexible container.
  It means align-items helps to align content vertically.

> flex-start and flex-end for justify-content means start and end (horizontally) of any container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

#main div {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The justify-content Property</h1>

<p>The "justify-content: flex-start;" aligns the flex items at the beginning of the container (this is default):</p>

<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">1</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">2</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">3</div>
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions do not support the justify-content property.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> Safari 6.1 (and newer) supports an alternative, the -webkit-justify-content property.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

(example taken from [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_justify-content3) .)

This will output all elements/objects to the leftmost end of the block/container.

> flex-start and flex-end for align-items means start and end (vertically) of any container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#main {
    width: 220px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black; 
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

#main div {
   -webkit-flex: 1; /* Safari 6.1+ */
   flex: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">RED</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">BLUE</div>  
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">Green div with more content.</div>
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions do not support the align-items property.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Safari 7.0 to 9.0 supports an alternative, the -webkit-align-items property.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

(example taken from [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_align-items) .)
This will output all elements/objects to the top of the block/container.